# Excel: Verify item from some conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, verification

I have some items that will price and others do not. Table 'full value' (Valor completo) show me what I should charge or not. I wanted, somehow, return a message: "You forgot to collect this item." or "You demanded an item that should not."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the English version of excel, you'd use

```
=iferror(vlookup(...),"You forgot to collect this item")
```

in brazilian, probably something like

```
=SEERRO(PROCV(...),"You forgot to collect this item")
```